# How to disable the rowsin Sheet1 based on values on other sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I an trying to disable rows in Sheet1 ,the range based on the values based on Sheet2. Sheet will comprise of rows with titles and Sheet2 will have title having value in either 0 or 1. Depending upon whether title value in Sheet2 is 0 or 1, it will be disabled or enabled in Sheet1.

0 Value in sheet 2 - Row should be disabled in Sheet1.

1 Value in Sheet2 - Row should be enabled in Sheet1.

Comment: Hello, is there a way to limit your range in sheet2? since if you want to check whole column in sheet2 and apply protection depending on values in that range, it is going to take long time i assume.

Comment: Dubison, there is a limit . I need to look for values of  around 20-30 rows in sheet2. and disable sheet1 rows accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I have added an answer below which will check first 50 cells in first column. Please let me know if you need further assist, if this is the answer for your question you can accept it as answer by clicking the button next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello please see below code, code will look in Sheet2 range A1 to A50 for "0" and "1" then lock same rows in sheet1 accordingly:

```
Sub LockingRows()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

ws1.Unprotect Password:="pass" '<--- Your password
ws1.Cells.Locked = False
For Each c In ws2.Range("A1:A50").Cells '<--- Your range to look in sheet2 for 0 and 1
    If c.Value = 1 Then
        ws1.Rows(c.Row & ":" & c.Row).Locked = True
        ElseIf c.Value = 0 Then
        ws1.Rows(c.Row & ":" & c.Row).Locked = False
    End If
Next
ws1.Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True '<--- Your password

End Sub
```

Comment: Dubison, Thanks for the answer .. Although it does not served my purpose completely but i got an Idea....